# contour integral with singularity on the contour

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, cauchy-principal-value

I want to compute the following integral 
$$\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{\exp \left (\frac{1}{z} \right)}{z^2-1}\,dz$$
The integrand has essential singularity at the origin, and $2$-poles at $\pm 1$,which lie on the curve $|z|=1$ so I can't apply residue formula. How can I proceed?

Comment: the integral doesn't exits in the usual sense; if you want the principal value (which is most probable) then you should count the two residues on the circle with $1/2$ (it works for simple poles

Comment: since this is a part of a bigger exercise with parameters ( here a=1 in the denominator) and the text says that for some values of $a$ the integral doesn't exists, i think this is the case. But how can i justify this? simply saying that residue formula doesn't apply?

Answer (score 9):

The integral as posed does not exist.  No Cauchy principal value will help this.  I can, however, pose a problem that is very close that will produce a pretty nifty result.

Consider

$$\oint_C dz \frac{e^{1/z}}{z^2-1} $$

where $C$ is the following contour:

[image]

i.e., the circle $|z|=1$ with semicircular notches of radius $\epsilon$ cut into the circle at the poles $z=\pm 1$.  By Cauchy's theorem, this integral is zero.  However, we can use this fact to deduce a nontrivial integral.

The contour integral is also equal to

$$i \int_{-\pi/2}^{-\epsilon} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{e^{e^{-i \theta}}}{e^{i 2 \theta}-1} + i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{e^{1/(1+\epsilon e^{i \phi})}}{(1+\epsilon e^{i \phi})^2-1} \\ + i \int_{\epsilon}^{\pi-\epsilon} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{e^{e^{-i \theta}}}{e^{i 2 \theta}-1} + i \epsilon \int_{\pi}^0 d\phi \, e^{i \phi} \frac{e^{1/(-1+\epsilon e^{i \phi})}}{(-1+\epsilon e^{i \phi})^2-1} \\ + i \int_{\pi+\epsilon}^{3 \pi/2} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{e^{e^{-i \theta}}}{e^{i 2 \theta}-1} $$

Note that the point at which I started and ended the integration on the circle is arbitrary; I chose it so that I was able to encompass the small semicircles in their entirety rather than split them up.  Now take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$, and I can simply express the Cauchy principal value over the circle over any interval of length $2 \pi$.  By Cauchy's theorem, we have

$$i PV \int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \, e^{i \theta} \frac{e^{e^{-i \theta}}}{e^{i 2 \theta}-1} - i \frac{\pi}{2} e + i \frac{\pi}{2} e^{-1} = 0 $$

Now separate out real and imaginary parts.  With a little manipulation, we may conclude the following:

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \frac{e^{\cos{\theta}} \sin{(\sin{\theta})}}{\sin{\theta}} = \pi \left ( e-\frac1{e}\right ) $$

$$PV \int_0^{2 \pi} d\theta \frac{e^{\cos{\theta}} \cos{(\sin{\theta})}}{\sin{\theta}} = 0$$

Sometimes it is interesting where these contour integrals can take us!

**ADDENDUM**

It is not trivial that the contour integral above is zero.  To show this, we need to expand the integrand in a Laurent series about $z=0$:

$$\frac{e^{1/z}}{z^2-1} = \left ( 1+\frac1{z} + \frac12 \frac1{z^2} + \cdots \right ) \frac1{z^2} \left (1+\frac1{z^2} + \cdots \right ) = \frac1{z^2} + \cdots$$

As there are no terms in $1/z$, the residue of this function at $z=0$ is zero, as is the integral.