# Integrate: $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2}dx$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to integrate $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^2(x)}{x^2} dx$  by method of contour. I am considering the following contour but I am not being able to. Also I am not sure if it's right approach.
[image: contour]

$$\int_\Gamma f(z) dz + 2 \int_0^\infty f(z) dz + \int_\gamma f(z)dz = 0$$
The first integral tends to zero as $R \to \infty $, but letting $\epsilon \to 0$, for the last integral I am getting.
$$\int_{\pi }^0 \frac{\sin^2({\epsilon e^{i\theta}})}{\epsilon^2 e^{i2\theta }} i \epsilon e^{i\theta}d\theta = 0$$

**ADDED**:: Taking the above contour, we do not have any pole inside the contour.
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1 - e^{i2z}}{2z^2}dz + \int_\Gamma \frac{1 - e^{i2z}}{2z^2} dz + \int_\gamma \frac{1 - e^{i2z}}{2z^2} dz = 0 \hspace{1 cm }(1)$$

$\displaystyle \int_\Gamma \frac{1 - e^{i2z}}{2z^2} dz \to 0$ due to Jordan Lemma. To evaluate $\displaystyle \int_\gamma \frac{1 - e^{i2z}}{2z^2} dz $ let the radius of the small semi circle be $\epsilon \to 0 $.

$$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_\pi^0 \frac{1 - e^{i2\epsilon e^{i\theta}}}{2\epsilon ^2 e^{i2\theta}} i \epsilon e^{i\theta}d\theta =\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\pi^0 \frac{1 - 1 - 2i\epsilon e^{i\theta} + O(\epsilon^2)}{2\epsilon e^{i\theta}} i  = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\pi^0 1+  O(\epsilon) d\theta = -\pi \hspace{1 cm }(2)$$

From $(2)$, $(1)$ reduces to 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1 - e^{i2z}}{2z^2}dz - \pi = 0 \implies \Re \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1 - e^{i2z}}{2z^2}dz = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(x)^2}{x^2}dx = \pi$$

**Including singularity** at $z = 0$, we will have that small inner circle on lower plane.
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1 - e^{i2z}}{2z^2}dz + \int_\Gamma \frac{1 - e^{i2z}}{2z^2} dz + \int_\gamma \frac{1 - e^{i2z}}{2z^2} dz = 2 \pi i \text{Residue}[f(z), z = 0] = 2\pi \hspace{1 cm }(3)$$

As for $\displaystyle \int_\gamma \frac{1 - e^{i2z}}{2z^2} dz = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\int_{-\pi}^0 \frac{1 - e^{i2\epsilon e^{i\theta}}}{2\epsilon ^2 e^{i2\theta}} i \epsilon e^{i\theta}d\theta = \pi \hspace{1 cm }(4)$

From $(3)$ and $(4)$ we get the same result.

Comment: No need (*informally*) to take that detour around zero, since $$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\sin^2z}{z^2}=1$$so we're talking of a removable singularity...

Comment: @DonAntonio I had encountered this type of contour in $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x} dx  = \frac{\pi}{2}$, so I considered it might work :=

Comment: Of course it works but *not* with your function...:) Read my answer.

Comment: @user17762: I disagree.  I am sure if you scour the M.SE posts you will find something similar, but that isn't it.  Besides, where in that post is this particular question being asked?  And, even so, it is unfair to the OP, who may not be as sophisticated as you, to call this a duplicate just because the problem is attacked more generally.

Comment: @RonGordon Actually there is no sophistication in the linked question. achille hui proves the general case using a similar if not the same contour.

Comment: @user17762 honestly that is too freaking complicated for a beginner like me :((

Comment: This question shouldn't be closed since the other option is wa too advanced and general for a beginner. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: This integral appeared in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13344/proof-for-an-integral-involving-sinc-function

Comment: @TCL the last answer by joriki is I am looking for. which did not understand as I mentioned in comments.

Comment: Hi! Well.. I think your "added" should have been an answer =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you try to do won't work since your function is (almost) analytic insde the path you take and thus won't help you to evaluate the real integral.

Let us try the following:

$$\cos 2x=1-2\sin^2x\implies \sin^2x=\frac{1-\cos2x}{2} \;\text{define}\;\;f(z):=\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{2z^2}:$$

$$\text{Res}_{z=0}(f)=\lim_{z\to 0}\,zf(z)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{1-e^{2iz}}{2z}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=-i$$

**Question:** The above implies $\,z=0\,$ is a *simple* pole...why is this so and **not** a double one?

Taking your contour, taking the limits and etc. **and** using the lemma and, specially, its corollary in the 2nd. answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83828/definite-integral-calculation-with-0-pole-and/184874#184874) , we get after comparing real and imaginary parts

$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}dx=\pi\;\;\ldots\ldots$$

Comment: Actually, it won't work because $\sin^2{z}$ does not converge on the outer contour.

Comment: @RonGordon, are you talking of my answer or of the intent the OP made with the function $\,\frac{\sin^2z}{z^2}\,$ ?

Comment: I am speaking of the first line in your answer: "What you try to do won't work since your function is (almost) analytic insde the path you take and thus won't help you to evaluate the real integral."  $\sin^2{z}$ has a component of $e^{-i 2 z}$ which does not behave nicely on the outer contour of radius $r$ as $r \to \infty$.  That is why using the function $\sin^2{z}/z^2$ won't work.

Comment: Well, perhaps...I'm not that sure, yet the complex integral of this function on that contour is zero and that *also* doesn't usually help to solve real integrals by means of complex integration...

Comment: If by "this function" you mean $\sin^2{z}/z^2$, you are wrong: the integral of this function over the above contour blows up as $r \to \infty$.  You need to take the piece you specify in the upper half plane, and another piece $(1-e^{-i 2 z})/z^2$ in the lower half-plane.

Comment: how come removable singularity changed into pole of order $1$ ?? is it due to $\sin $ component since we introduced $e^{i2z}$ ??

Comment: Also what kind of contour do I need? should i extend it a bit below upper half plane to include $(0,0)$ ... since there is singularity at the path. There is also a question which has no answers. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/246701/contour-integral-with-singularity-on-the-contour

Comment: Perhaps it blows ( I didn't check that ), yet it still vanishes in the shown contour, @RonGordon (in case you were addressing me...)

Comment: @MulaKoSaag, did you notice that you worked with one function and I did work with **another** function ?

Comment: @DonAntonio yes I saw that, but still I can't visualize the picture of contour. There is a pole of order $1$ at $z=0$. What contour do I need to consider such that there is no singularity on the path.

Comment: @MulaKoSaag, please: since we have at least two different functions, when you say "there is a pole..." do write explicitly to what function you refer.

Comment: $f(z) := \frac{1 - e^{i2z}}{z^2}$ this function has a pole of order $1$ at $z=0$. I found my answer here ,,, http://math.stackexchange.com/a/382975/69881,,, but I am having trouble understand joriki's answer. How does he transit from 4 - to - 5 step?

Comment: Yes @MulaKoSaag, that's precisely what I wrote: that the function I chose has a simple pole at $\,z=0\,$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio could you check update?

Comment: I already did, @Mula: Use the very same contour you chose at the beginning but with the function I used!! Then check carefully the link I wrote there and you get your answer at once.

Comment: Could you explain one more thing? how did you change $f(z) := \frac{1-e^{i2z}}{z^2}$ to $f(z) := \frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}$. I am [getting residue](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Residue%5B%281-e%5E%28i2z%29%29%2Fz%5E2%2C+%7Bz%2C+0%7D%5D) to be $2i$

Comment: Thanks to your question about the change I discovered a huge blunder from the trigonometric identity. I already edited my answer, thanks.

Comment: I think we can solve this without taking residue at $z = 0$ also. If we take residue at $z = 0$, then I think we will be taking that curve $\gamma $ will be on lower plane. Please check my working.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more easier way From this [Evaluating the integral $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x} x \ dx = \frac \pi 2$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-x-dx-frac-pi-2) We know that , $$\frac{\pi}{2} =\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x} dx =  \int_0^\infty\frac{\sin 2u}{2u} d(2u) =\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin 2u}{u} du\\ = \underbrace{\left[\frac{\sin^2 u}{u}\right]_0^\infty}_{=0} +\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2u}{u^2} du =\color{blue}{\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^2u}{u^2} du} $$

> Given that, $\sin2x = 2\sin x\cos x=(\sin^2x)'$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2} = 1$